# настройка или перенаправление портов vpn на Raspberry

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi, openvpn, порты

на распберри установлен хоум ассистент и норде для организации умного. локально к ней подключены wi-fi устройства и hokekit

когда на распберри включаю впн клиент (для удалённого подключения извне к этой распберри) то отваливаются вайфай устройства из хомассистента и не работает хомкит. добил умный дом перестаёт работать как локально так и удалённо. выключаю впн - всё через минуту-две начинает работать работать нормально.

я так понимаю что малинка весь трафик пускает через впн, а надо чтобы только удаленное подключение было через впн, а всё остальное локально

как можно решить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы перенаправить только удаленное подключение через VPN, вам нужно настроить маршрутизацию трафика вашей системы так, чтобы он не проходил через VPN для локальных сетей.

Для этого вы можете воспользоваться командой route. Например, если ваша VPN-сеть имеет адрес 10.8.0.0/24, то вы можете выполнить следующую команду, чтобы добавить маршрут для локальных сетей:

```
route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth0
```

Эта команда добавит маршрут для сетей с адресами вида 192.168.x.x, которые будут использовать устройство eth0 (это обычно ваша локальная сеть) для передачи трафика.

Вы также можете указать отдельный маршрут для удаленных сетей, которые будут использовать VPN для передачи трафика. Например:

```
route add default gw 10.8.0.1
```

Эта команда добавит маршрут по умолчанию через VPN-шлюз 10.8.0.1. Все удаленные сети, которые не совпадают с маршрутами, определенными выше, будут использовать этот маршрут по умолчанию.

Чтобы убедиться, что маршруты были успешно добавлены, вы можете выполнить команду route -n. Эта команда покажет текущие маршруты системы.

Примечание: Эти команды будут работать только до следующего перезапуска системы. Чтобы сделать изменения постоянными, вам нужно будет добавить их в конфигурационный файл системы.

Comment: спасибо, сегодня попробую, отпишусь

Comment: У меня на VPN вот такой адрес у подключённого устройства - 192.168.224.10. вводил команды, но не помогло

Comment: К вопросу прикрепил картинку с результатом команды route -n